# Problem in inserting default data into form Group

Tags: angular

I have a real problem in my update dialog, I have a form that I need to fill it by user info but I found many problems like:

1) Fields like (DriverCode/CIN) that has an array of validations can't be validated only when I delete that fields and refill it again [The submit button still disable, it will be enabled when I delete the fields and refill it], Rq if I click on one field of them then click on another field or outside I found the mat-error fire. for example, here I have [Validators.minLength(4),Validators.maxLength(4),Validators.required] on the field and I click inside the code Personne field than outside.
[image]

2) I found that The submit button still disable until I change or put data into date picker I don't know why!

My Html:

```
<div mat-dialog-content class="p-16 pb-0 m-0" fusePerfectScrollbar>

        <form [formGroup]="profileForm" class="event-form w-100-p" fxLayout="column" fxFlex>

            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="w-100-p">
                <mat-label>Nom*</mat-label>
                <input matInput
                       formControlName="Nom_de_famille">
                <mat-error>tu faux remplir ce champs.</mat-error>

            </mat-form-field>



            <div fxFlex="1 0 auto" fxLayout="column" fxLayout.gt-xs="row">

                <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="pr-sm-8" fxFlex="50">
                    <mat-label>Prénom*</mat-label>
                    <input matInput formControlName="Prénom">
                    <mat-error>tu faux remplir ce champs.</mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>

                <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="pr-sm-8" fxFlex="50">
                    <mat-label>email*</mat-label>
                    <mat-error>L'email n'est pas valider.</mat-error>
                    <input matInput formControlName="email">
                </mat-form-field>

            </div>

            <div fxFlex="1 0 auto" fxLayout="column" fxLayout.gt-xs="row">

                <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="pr-sm-8" fxFlex="50">
                    <mat-label>Code personnel*</mat-label>
                    <input matInput formControlName="Code_personnel">
                    <mat-error>Code personnel doit composer par 4 chiffres.</mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>

                <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="pr-sm-8" fxFlex="50">
                    <mat-label>N de tel</mat-label>
                    <input matInput formControlName="N_tel">
                </mat-form-field>

            </div>
            <div fxFlex="1 0 auto" fxLayout="column" fxLayout.gt-xs="row">

                <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="pr-sm-8" fxFlex="100">
                    <mat-label>Date de naissance</mat-label>
                    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="startDatePicker"  formControlName="birthday">
                    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="startDatePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                    <mat-datepicker #startDatePicker ></mat-datepicker>
                </mat-form-field>

            </div>
            <div fxFlex="1 0 auto" fxLayout="column" fxLayout.gt-xs="row">

                <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="pr-sm-8" fxFlex="50">
                    <mat-label>Lieu de naissance</mat-label>
                    <input matInput formControlName="lieu">
                </mat-form-field>
                <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="pr-sm-8" fxFlex="50">
                    <mat-label>Adresse</mat-label>
                    <input matInput formControlName="adresse">
                </mat-form-field>


            </div>
            <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxFlex="1 0 auto">

                <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" required>
                    <mat-label>Departement*</mat-label>
                    <mat-select formControlName="Département" >
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let dept of departements" [value]="dept.id">{{dept.name}}</mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
                    <mat-icon matSuffix class="secondary-text">outlined_flag</mat-icon>

                    <mat-error>Selecter le departement</mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>

            </div>
            <div fxFlex="1 0 auto" fxLayout="column" fxLayout.gt-xs="row">

                <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="pr-sm-8" fxFlex="100">
                    <mat-label>N° de CIN*</mat-label>
                    <input matInput formControlName="CIN">
                    <mat-error>le valeur de CIN n'est pas valider.</mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>
            </div>
            <div fxFlex="1 0 auto" fxLayout="column" fxLayout.gt-xs="row">

                <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="pr-sm-8" fxFlex="50">
                    <mat-label>Genre du permis de conduire</mat-label>
                    <input matInput formControlName="Genre">
                </mat-form-field>
                <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="pr-sm-8" fxFlex="50">
                    <mat-label>N° du permis du conduire</mat-label>
                    <input matInput formControlName="N_permis">
                </mat-form-field>
            </div>
           <!--- <mat-select  formControlName="Département" placeholder="Departement" [(ngModel)]="selected" class="drop_list">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let dept of departements" [value]="dept.id">{{dept.name}}</mat-option>
                <mat-error>Selecter un deparetement.</mat-error>
            </mat-select>-->
        </form>

    </div>

    <div mat-dialog-actions class="m-0 p-16" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="end center">

        <button  mat-button color="primary"
                class="save-button"
                (click)="onaccept()"
                [disabled]="profileForm.invalid"
                aria-label="ADD">
                {{ActionType}}
        </button>

    </div>
```

My component.ts

```
export class EditNewChauffeursComponent implements OnInit {
  profileForm = this.fb.group({
    Nom_de_famille: ['' ,Validators.required],//
    Prénom: ['' ,Validators.required],//
    email: ['', [Validators.email,Validators.required]],//
    Code_personnel: ['',[Validators.minLength(4),Validators.maxLength(4),Validators.required]],//Validators.required
    N_tel: [''],
    birthday: [],
    adresse: [''],
    lieu:[''],
    CIN:['',[Validators.minLength(8),Validators.maxLength(8),Validators.required]],
    Genre:[''],
    N_permis:[''],
    Département: ['',Validators.required]
  });
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
 ngOnInit() {
if(this.indata==null){//New user
      this.dialogTitle = "Ajouter un chauffeur";
     }else{//Update user
       this.dialogTitle = "Modifier un chauffeur";
       this.setdefaultformvalues(this.indata.SendData);
     }
}
  setdefaultformvalues(row) {
    this.profileForm.patchValue({
      Nom_de_famille: [row.FirstName],
      Prénom: [row.LastName],
      email: [row.Email],
      Code_personnel: [row.DriverCode],
      N_tel: [row.Tel],
      birthday: [],
      adresse: [row.Address],
      lieu:[row.BirthPlace],
      CIN:[row.CIN],
      Genre:[row.DriverLicenseType],
      N_permis:[row.DriverLicenseNumber],
      Département: [row.DepartmentId]
    });

  }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case , if you don't know , you can use a `MatFormField` of type number by default and limit the valid value between `1000` and `9999` ( 4 digits) : Stackblitz exemple : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nd6q2u?file=src/app/form-field-theming-example.ts

Comment: Ok thanks that solves my first problem still the second one